# Symfony2, How to secure all controllers in one place using custom function?

Tags: security, symfony

I have defined my controller but I would like to secure ALL of them like below :

```
// In my Controller Class 
public function chooseDateAction()
{
    if($this->get('MY.roles_features')
            ->isGranted($this->container->get('request')->get('_route')))
    {
         // Do something 

    }
    else
    {
        throw new AccessDeniedException();
    }


    return array( );
}
```

I had to design my own 'isGranted' function because `roles` are dynamic. BTW the function is working properly !

So my question is do I have to repeat the `isGranted` function in all of my `Controllers` or I can put it somewhere to reduce the code redundancy.

I know I have to place `isGranted` in some top level layer of my security, But the question is how and where ?

Comment: Sorry but ... this is a security stuff that you can manage in security.yml. In firewall settings. Or not?

Answer (score 5):

Try writing a base controller, which will check upon construction, if `isGranted` method passes, else throws exception. e.g.:

```
<?php

namespace Acme\DolanBundle\Controller;

use Symfony\Bundle\FrameworkBundle\Controller\Controller;
use Symfony\Component\Security\Core\Exception\AccessDeniedException;

class BaseController extends Controller
{

    public function __construct()
    {
         if(!$this->get('MY.roles_features')
                  ->isGranted($this->container->get('request')->get('_route')))
        {
         throw new AccessDeniedException('Gooby pls');
        }
    }
}
```

Then just extend the BaseController in your other controllers.

Comment: I'm 100% sure that the code in __construct method in a controller is executed in every action, even in the inheriting controllers. That's basic OOP.